# convert integer to 4 digit decimal in hour format

Tags: javascript

I need to write a function where i got one input parameter that can be a number from 1 to 9999. I need that output always be in a 4 digits format with a point between the numbers. For example, if the input is 1, the output must be 00,01. Input 157, ouput 01,57, and so on. Thanks

Comment: Could you show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: you convert the number to a string, pad it with leading 0's then insert whatever "point" character you want in the appropriate place - which one of those do you have an issue with

Comment: thanks @JaromandaX. I didnt know about this pad function in JS.

Comment: homework assignment?

Comment: Just part of my junior job :X. I needed this to converte a input in a time transit of a train inside a software

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consider utilizing [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) and [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice):

```js
const formatNum = num => {
  if (!Number.isInteger(num)) throw "num must be an integer!";
  if (num < 1 || num > 9999) throw "num must be between 1 and 9999 inclusive!";
  const paddedNum = String(num).padStart(4, '0');
  // TODO(@marcelo-teixeira-modesti): Add check to see if valid time as per train software requirements...
  return `${paddedNum.slice(0, 2)},${paddedNum.slice(2)}`;
}

console.log(formatNum(1));
console.log(formatNum(157));
console.log(formatNum(2356));
```